# autorun picamera script in rc.local doesnt actually record video

Tags: python, boot, camera, raspicam

I have the following code which I can run normally to record video, using `python3 button_led_video.py`, however when I put it into `/etc/rc.local` the camera no longer records video. Here is the `python3` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gpiozero import Button
from gpiozero import LED
from picamera import PiCamera
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

# setup camera and button
camera = PiCamera()
button = Button(4)
led = LED(17)

# recording flag
is_recording = 0

try:
    # calibrate the camera
    camera.start_preview()
    print("CALIBRATING...")
    sleep(2)
    print("READY TO RECORD!")
    print()

    while True:
        if (button.value == True) and (is_recording == 0):
            print("RECORDING")
            x = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%m-%s')
            camera.start_recording('video-' + x + '.h264')
            is_recording = 1
            led.on()

        elif (button.value == False) and (is_recording == 1):
            print("DONE RECORDING!")
            camera.stop_recording()
            is_recording = 0
            led.off()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("INTERRUPTED!")
    button.close()
    camera.close()
    led.close()
```

Here is how I have it in `/etc/rc.local`: `sudo python3 /path/to/file.py &`

When I make file.py `executable` and add the above line to `/etc/rc.local`, following a reboot (when I would expect the script to run on its own) I am able to get the LED to light up but nothing happens with the camera (no new video files appear after pressing, holding, and then releasing the button). If I try to run `rc.local` manually at this point by simply running `/etc/rc.local` I get an error that ends with: `picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources`

I am totally stuck on this, as it works outside of `/etc/rc.local` reliably. Can someone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? I am trying to get a point and shoot video camera going here and this is problem is cramping my style.

Comment: update: tried adding `camera.close()` after `camera.stop_recording()` with no improvement in symptoms. video file still does not appear though script appears to be running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got in touch with the maintainer of the `picamera` library [here](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/issues/426) and have resolved issues. Here is a list of changes that need to be made to get this to work:

1. `start_recording()` needs a full path to explicitly tell it where to save, otherwise it will save to `/`. I made the following changes to do so:

   ```
   x = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%m-%s')
   path = ''.join(['/home/pi/', x, '.h264'])
   camera.start_recording(path)
   ```
2. the line in `/etc/rc.local` needs to be written like this in order to run under the `pi` user and therefore properly save the file in `/home/pi/`: `su -c "python3 /path/to/file.py" pi &`

After making both of these changes the code in the initial question, which was apparently always working and just saving to a different place, will work properly.